# Display MAX value and Corresponding value BOTH

Tags: excel

I have this table.

```
Name | Score | House | Badge 
xxx    100
yyy    200
zzz    300
```

Now I know to display the MAX value with 
`MAX(B1:B3)`
And I also Know to display its corresponding value with 
`=INDEX(B1:B3,MATCH(MAX(C1:C3),C1:C3,0))`

But what if I want to display Both. Like 
zzz 300

How do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

concatenate your formulas to make a string in a single cell:

```
=INDEX(A1:A3,MATCH(MAX(B1:B3),B1:B3,0))&" "&MAX(B1:B3)
```

Comment: It only gives Max value.